# Fitbit oauth2.0 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I am getting invalid redirect uri for the below code.

**startup.cs**

```
services.AddOAuth(options => { 
options.AuthenticationScheme = "FitBit-AccessToken"; 
options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize"; options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token"; 
options.SaveTokensAsClaims = true; 
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signing-fitbit-token/"); 
options.ClientId = "[MY ID STRIPPED OUT]"; 
options.ClientSecret = "[MY SECRET STRIPPED OUT]"; 
options.DisplayName = "FitBit"; 
options.Scope.Add("activity"); 
options.Scope.Add("heartrate"); 
options.Scope.Add("location"); 
options.Scope.Add("nutrition"); 
options.Scope.Add("profile"); 
options.Scope.Add("settings"); 
options.Scope.Add("sleep"); 
options.Scope.Add("social"); 
options.Scope.Add("weight"); 
options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true; });
```

**FitbitController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FitBit_Oauth.Controllers
{
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class FitbitController : Controller
{
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = $"/" });
}
}
}
```

I have tried this to authenticate fitbit user and retrieve access token, but I am getting invalid redirect_uri.

Can anyone suggest here, how to implement it in asp.net core MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your requirements are, but rather than doing this yourself you could [Fitbit.Net](https://github.com/aarondcoleman/Fitbit.NET).  It's not perfect, but it takes a lot of the leg work out of it.